# R: SQLDF returning an empty result

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset ("df"):

```
df <- structure(list(student = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                       var1 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"),
                       start = structure(c(14610, 14610, 15869, 17439, 14610, 16436, 17897), class = "Date"),
                       end = structure(c(15706, 15706, 16679, 17723, 16071, 17492, 18791), class = "Date")),
                  row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")


  student var1      start        end
1       1    a 2010-01-01 2013-01-01
2       1    b 2010-01-01 2013-01-01
3       1    b 2013-06-13 2015-09-01
4       1    a 2017-09-30 2018-07-11
5       2    c 2010-01-01 2014-01-01
6       2    a 2015-01-01 2017-11-22
7       2    b 2019-01-01 2021-06-13
```

**My Problem:** Using the SQLDF library in R, I am trying to run the following code (to see if each student between each year (from march 1st 2010 - march 1st 2020) had at least one instance of var1=a):

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("WITH date_ranges AS (
  SELECT '2010-03-01' AS start_date, '2011-03-01' AS end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2012-03-01', '2013-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2013-03-01', '2014-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2014-03-01', '2015-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-03-01', '2016-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2016-03-01', '2017-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-03-01', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-03-01', '2019-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-03-01', '2020-03-01'
), 
joined_data AS (
  SELECT 
    t.student,
    d.start_date,
    d.end_date,
    t.var1
  FROM 
   df t
  JOIN 
    date_ranges d
  ON 
    t.start <= d.end_date AND t.end >= d.start_date
)

select * from joined_data;")
```

However, this is returning a NULL result:

```
[1] student    start_date end_date   var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

**Can someone please help me understand why this is happening and what I can do to avoid this?**

Thanks!

- **Note:**

Here is the full code I would have used to solve this problem

```
 sqldf("WITH date_ranges AS (
      SELECT '2010-03-01' AS start_date, '2011-03-01' AS end_date UNION ALL
      SELECT '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2012-03-01', '2013-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2013-03-01', '2014-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2014-03-01', '2015-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2015-03-01', '2016-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2016-03-01', '2017-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2017-03-01', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2018-03-01', '2019-03-01' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2019-03-01', '2020-03-01'
    ), 
    joined_data AS (
      SELECT 
        t.student,
        d.start_date,
        d.end_date,
        t.var1
      FROM 
       df t
      JOIN 
        date_ranges d
      ON 
        t.start <= d.end_date AND t.end >= d.start_date
    ), var1_counts AS (
      SELECT 
        student,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN var1 = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS var1_count
      FROM 
        joined_data
      GROUP BY 
        student, start_date, end_date
    )
    SELECT 
      student,
      start_date,
      end_date,
      CASE WHEN var1_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS at_least_one_var1_a
    FROM 
      var1_counts;
    
    select * from joined_data;")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Convert the `start` and `end` columns to characters after creating `df`, and the code should work fine:

```
df$start <- as.character(df$start) 
df$end <- as.character(df$end)
```

#### Explanation

The issue with the original code is that the `start_date` and `end_date` are taken directly from the `structure()` as integer numbers, which leads to the date conversion and comparison failing. To verify:

```
> df <- structure(list(student = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
+                      var1 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"),
+                      start = structure(c(14610, 14610, 15869, 17439, 14610, 16436, 17897), class = "Date"),
+                      end = structure(c(15706, 15706, 16679, 17723, 16071, 17492, 18791), class = "Date")),
+                 row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
> sqldf("SELECT 
+       start, 
+       STRFTIME('%s', start) AS start_strf, 
+       end, 
+       STRFTIME('%s', end) AS end_strf 
+       FROM df") 
       start    start_strf        end      end_strf
1 2010-01-01 -209604456000 2013-01-01 -209509761600
2 2010-01-01 -209604456000 2013-01-01 -209509761600
3 2013-06-13 -209495678400 2015-09-01 -209425694400
4 2017-09-30 -209360030400 2018-07-11 -209335492800
5 2010-01-01 -209604456000 2014-01-01 -209478225600
6 2015-01-01 -209446689600 2017-11-22 -209355451200
7 2019-01-01 -209320459200 2021-06-13 -209243217600
```

We can see that although the `start` and `end` times seem to be in the correct format, the POSIXct times are all negative. This means the integer values rather than the date strings might be taken to compute dates in SQLite (e.g., (`sqldf("SELECT STRFTIME('%s', 14610)")` returns `-209604456000`)).

To fix this, we need to ensure that the data we pass into SQL is in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format (SQLite represents dates as ISO8601 strings, Julian dates, or POSIXct timestamps - [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)). We can achieve this by converting the `start` and `end` columns within the `df` dataframe into literal date strings.

```
df$start <- as.character(df$start) 
df$end <- as.character(df$end)
```

Then we retry the code above:

```
> df <- structure(list(student = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
+                      var1 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"),
+                      start = structure(c(14610, 14610, 15869, 17439, 14610, 16436, 17897), class = "Date"),
+                      end = structure(c(15706, 15706, 16679, 17723, 16071, 17492, 18791), class = "Date")),
+                 row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
> df$end <- as.character(df$end) 
> df$start <- as.character(df$start) 
> sqldf("SELECT 
+       start, 
+       STRFTIME('%s', start) AS start_strf, 
+       end, 
+       STRFTIME('%s', end) AS end_strf 
+       FROM df") 
       start start_strf        end   end_strf
1 2010-01-01 1262304000 2013-01-01 1356998400
2 2010-01-01 1262304000 2013-01-01 1356998400
3 2013-06-13 1371081600 2015-09-01 1441065600
4 2017-09-30 1506729600 2018-07-11 1531267200
5 2010-01-01 1262304000 2014-01-01 1388534400
6 2015-01-01 1420070400 2017-11-22 1511308800
7 2019-01-01 1546300800 2021-06-13 1623542400
```

Now that we have the correct time format, your code should work fine:

```
> sqldf("WITH date_ranges AS (
+       SELECT '2010-03-01' AS start_date, '2011-03-01' AS end_date UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2012-03-01', '2013-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2013-03-01', '2014-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2014-03-01', '2015-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2015-03-01', '2016-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2016-03-01', '2017-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2017-03-01', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2018-03-01', '2019-03-01' UNION ALL
+       SELECT '2019-03-01', '2020-03-01'
+     ), 
+     joined_data AS (
+       SELECT 
+         t.student,
+         d.start_date,
+         d.end_date,
+         t.var1
+       FROM 
+        df t
+       JOIN 
+         date_ranges d
+       ON 
+         strftime('%s', t.start) <= strftime('%s', d.end_date) AND strftime('%s', t.end) >= strftime('%s', d.start_date)
+     ), var1_counts AS (
+       SELECT 
+         student,
+         start_date,
+         end_date,
+         COUNT(CASE WHEN var1 = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS var1_count
+       FROM 
+         joined_data
+       GROUP BY 
+         student, start_date, end_date
+     )
+     SELECT 
+       student,
+       start_date,
+       end_date,
+       CASE WHEN var1_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS at_least_one_var1_a
+     FROM 
+       var1_counts;")
   student start_date   end_date at_least_one_var1_a
1        1 2010-03-01 2011-03-01                 Yes
2        1 2011-03-01 2012-03-01                 Yes
3        1 2012-03-01 2013-03-01                 Yes
4        1 2013-03-01 2014-03-01                  No
5        1 2014-03-01 2015-03-01                  No
6        1 2015-03-01 2016-03-01                  No
7        1 2017-03-01 2018-03-01                 Yes
8        1 2018-03-01 2019-03-01                 Yes
9        2 2010-03-01 2011-03-01                  No
10       2 2011-03-01 2012-03-01                  No
11       2 2012-03-01 2013-03-01                  No
12       2 2013-03-01 2014-03-01                  No
13       2 2014-03-01 2015-03-01                 Yes
14       2 2015-03-01 2016-03-01                 Yes
15       2 2016-03-01 2017-03-01                 Yes
16       2 2017-03-01 2018-03-01                 Yes
17       2 2018-03-01 2019-03-01                  No
18       2 2019-03-01 2020-03-01                  No
```

Comment: Also see sqldf FAQ #4 - https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf